# Change attributes defined in defs on use element

Tags: svg

How can I achieve changing the style of an "use element", defined in defs, through scripting? I was trying to move in the w3c working draft interfaces, but I lost in that labyrinth

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<svg
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
   width="100"
   height="100"
   id="svg1">

<defs>
   <g id="minchia" onclick="color(evt)">
     <rect width="50" height="50" style="fill:#ffff6e;stroke:#ee1400;stroke-width:3" />
   </g>
</defs>       

<script type="text/javascript"> 
<![CDATA[ 
function color(evt)
{   
    node = evt.target.correspondingUseElement;

    alert(node.getAttributeNS(null, "style"));   /* empty! */
    alert(node.getAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "style"));   /* empty! */

    node.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "fill", "blue");    /* nothing */
    node.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "blue");  /* nothing */
}
]]> 
</script>

<use xlink:href="#minchia" id="frufru" x="10" y="10"  />       
</svg>
```

**Update**

One more thing: what if the referenced element is a "g" which contains 2 other elements, like a rect and a text? How do I set the attribute for the right childNode (through DOM methods off course)?
In this example, the setAttribute is styling the first child of the referenced element. What if I had to style the second one?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<svg
  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  version="1.1"
  width="1000"
  height="1000"
  id="svg1">

<defs>
  <g id="test" onclick="color(evt)" >
 <rect
   width="54"
   height="58"
   x="1.5"
   y="1.5"
   id="rect5" />
<text
   x="-34"
   y="47"
   transform="matrix(0.66777386,-0.74436421,0.74436421,0.66777386,0,0)"
   id="text2987"
   style="font-size:30px;fill:#ffffff;stroke-width:0px">JC!</text>
 </g>
</defs>       

<script type="text/javascript"> 
<![CDATA[ 
function color(evt)
{   
node = evt.target.correspondingUseElement;
    node.setAttributeNS(null, "style", "fill:blue");    
}
]]> 
</script>

<use xlink:href="#test" id="frufru" x="10" y="10" style="fill:#000000" />       

</svg>
```

Answer (score 38):

As you can see in [my test page](http://phrogz.net/svg/use_style_precedence.xhtml), if you define the visual style of an element inside the `<defs>` section of a document you cannot override that style on the `<use>` instance, not through a visual attribute, `style` attribute, or CSS class applied to the `<use>`.

[image: Snapshot of test results from linked SVG file, showing that only unstyled elements can be overridden]

*Further, you cannot use a visual attribute on the `<use>` element to cascade styles down to elements of the source; you must use CSS styling for this.*

You'll have to:

1. Ensure that your defined elements have no visual style applied, and
2. Use either CSS or set a manually-parsed-or-created `style` attribute, e.g.

   ```js
   node.setAttribute('style','fill:blue');
   ```

*As [noted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882890/svg-in-xhtml5-setting-attributes-with-proper-namespace) you can use either `setAttribute(...)` or `setAttributeNS(null,...)` for SVG attributes.*

**Update**: To answer your second question:

> *What if the referenced element is a "g" which contains 2 other elements, like a rect and a text?*

You cannot use CSS rules to select the pseudo-children of a `<use>`; they simply don't exist. What you can do, however, is apply the unchanging styling that you want to preserve inside the `<def>` and then apply the `style` you want on the `<use>`.

For example:

```xml
<defs>
  <g id="foo">
    <!-- Every rect instance should be filled with blue -->
    <rect width="54" height="58" x="1.5" y="1.5"
          fill="blue" />
    <!-- I want to be able to change text color per use
         so I must be sure not to specify the fill style -->
    <text x="-34" y="47" transform="matrix(0.668,-0.744,0.744,0.668,0,0)"
     style="font-size:30px;stroke-width:0px">JC!</text>
  </g>
</defs>
<use xlink:href="#foo" style="fill:orange" transform="translate(0,-100)" />
<use xlink:href="#foo" style="fill:yellow" transform="translate(0, 100)" />
```

This only works if you want all changeable items to have their attributes set the same way.

Unlike HTML, the markup in SVG *is* the presentation. What I've suggested above is a bit of a hack that happens to work, but in general `<use>` elements are designed to instantiate the full appearance of a definition. If you need custom appearance per instance, perhaps you should consider cloning elements, modifying properties, and adding those to the document instead of hacking a `<use>`.

Comment: I merged his answer with his question.

Comment: Great answer, but possible that we have better support in FF now than at the time you wrote this. CSS styling still does not penetrate into psuedo-elements within `<use>` elements in webkit, but if FF it seems to work very well. Cross your fingers for better support soon!

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Phrogz answer, It looks like even if i try to overwrite the styles defined inside the `symbol` tag its not getting overwritten in the use tag. A fiddle for that http://jsfiddle.net/rajkamal/xrdgf/

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, thanks to [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) and some clever `<div>` nesting, it can be done.
Check out my [CodePen here](https://codepen.io/luketobrien/pen/rNaGZWa)

The trick is to contain your SVG in a `div` and set the style variables in a nested `<style>` tag:

```
<div class="svg-container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 30 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <style>
      div.svg-container {
        --stroke: red;
        --fill: blue;
      }
    </style>
    <circle id="myCircle" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" style="stroke:var(--stroke);fill:var(--fill);"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="svg-container circle-1">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 30 10"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">  
    <use href="#myCircle" x="10"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Notice that the style rule here points to the `div.class`?
Now in you CSS file you can make a more specific rule pointing to the `<svg>` within the container:

```
.circle-1 svg {
  --stroke: yellow;
  --fill: salmon;
}
```

> Note: I did experiment to get this working, it was tricky ;-)