# Trying to theme a part of an SVG based on the class it is nested in

Tags: css, svg, sprite

This is a rather complex question, so please let me know if my explanation confuses you.  I have a [working demo](http://codepen.io/FlyersPh9/pen/QbWXQK?editors=110) which will help you further understand the situation.  I will explain in bullet points:

- I am following [Chris Coyier's method for SVG sprites](https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/).
- I have three columns displaying the same SVG icons.

  - Column one is themeless.
  - Column two has a theme for light backgrounds.
  - Column three has a theme for dark backgrounds.
- The theme is applied to the icon based on the SVG class like this:
  `<svg class="icon theme-light"><use xlink:href="#shape-search" /></svg>`

Now here is where I am running into problems.  The search icon has two parts: the magnifying glass and the lense (class `.lense`).  The lense fill is set as `fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.0)"` within the sprite file.  This is done so the lense does NOT appear when no theme is applied.

I want the lense to appear when targeted.  I thought that `.theme-light .lense {fill: rgba(0,255,0,1.0);}` would work, but it does not.  I could do `.lense {fill: rgba(0,255,0,1.0);}` but then the lense is styled the same for all three themes which I do not want. Any recommendations on what I can do to target specific parts of an SVG based on which theme class it falls under?

Here are all the resources I have available for you to take a look at to better understand the problem:

- [My working demo](http://codepen.io/FlyersPh9/pen/QbWXQK?editors=110)
- [My SVG sprite](http://codepen.io/FlyersPh9/pen/XbWLZV?editors=100)
- The search icon's SVG code:

  ```
  <symbol id="shape-search" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <circle id="lense" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.0)" cx="12" cy="12" r="9"/>
      <path d="M32,29.2L21.8,18.9c1.4-2,2.2-4.4,2.2-6.9c0-6.6-5.4-12-12-12S0,5.4,0,12c0,6.6,5.4,12,12,12c2.6,0,5-0.8,6.9-2.2L29.2,32L32,29.2z M4,12c0-4.4,3.6-8,8-8s8,3.6,8,8c0,4.4-3.6,8-8,8S4,16.4,4,12z"/>
  </symbol>
  ```

Comment: Any chance you could reduce the demo to managable size...there's no real reason to have **every** svg there. You're only after a concept after all.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't "reach inside" a `use` element like that though.

Comment: @Paulie_D Ok, links have been updated.

Comment: As I mentioned, my understanding is that you cannot use CSS rules to select the pseudo-children of a <use>. This question has a lot of information - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069006/change-attributes-defined-in-defs-on-use-element